# Shell alias with set -e to make command fail?

Tags: shell, alias

So we have an alias that does:

```
alias doIt='cd somedir; rm -rf *'
```

What we want is for the command to fail immediately if, for example, somedir does not exist.  This protects us from getting the rm -rf bomb in an inconvienient location. 
Is something like this possible? If not, is there another way?:

```
alias doIt='set -e; cd somedir; rm -rf *'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
alias doit='cd somedir && rm -rf *'
```

the `rm -rf *` won't be executed if `cd somedir` fails.

Comment: This is correct. But in this specific case, `rm -rf somedir/*` would have worked too?

Comment: @Konerak right, but that doesn't have the exact same meaning. I'll err on the side of caution assuming that everything else relies on actually changing to `somedir`

Comment: Not the exact same meaning? Can you enlighten me, give an example where it would be different?

Comment: @Konerak the current directory after `cd somedir && rm -rf *` is `somedir`, whereas the current directory after `rm -rf somedir/*` is whatever directory you were initially in.